# iOS how to parse "MM/DD/YY HH:MM AM" using NSDateFormatter on a device with 24 hour clock?

Tags: ios, objective-c, timestamp, nsdateformatter

I'm running into a weird issue where the following code seems to ignore time format I specify and uses 24 hour time (my phone is in 24 hour time).

I tried NSDateFormatterShortStyle for timeStyle and get weird results like 14:36 PM, while I expect 2:36PM

**How can I specify a date format for NSDateFormatter regardless of the device's clock setting?**

```
            static NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = nil;
            static dispatch_once_t anotherOnceToken;
            dispatch_once(&anotherOnceToken, ^{
                dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    //            dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"MM/dd/yy hh:mm a";
    //            dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterShortStyle;
                dateFormatter.dateFormat =@"MM/dd/yy hh:mm a";
            });

        NSString* dateString = @"07/20/15 11:16 AM";
        NSDate* date =  [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];

//trying the reverse - prints 09/10/15 14:31
        NSString* dateTestString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

Comment: Which part isn't working? `dateFromString:` or `stringFromDate:`?

Comment: Suggested fix:      NSLocale* enUSPOSIXLocale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
            [dateFormatter setLocale:enUSPOSIXLocale];